# Can I just drop features that are clearly not important without using any feature selection techniques?

Tags: machine-learning, feature-selection, feature-engineering, data-preprocessing

I'm working on a M.L project that predicts the prices of different courses in Udemy, there are some columns in the dataset that are not related to the price like(published_timestamp, course_url, course_ID) before performing any feature selection technique to decide the most important features that I should include I want to drop the past columns from the dataset because they are clearly not related to what I want to predict, can I?

...............................................................

Comment: This is a machine learning question not a programming question; you should ask it on Cross Validated. But the short answer is: of course you can. You're allowed to bring domain knowledge to the problem. But you can also use feature importance measures, tree models, CV, or L1 regularization (etc, etc) to help prove your hypothesis that the features are not useful. That's what data science is all about.

Comment: This is a machine learning question not a programming question; you should ask it on Cross Validated. But the short answer is: of course you can. You're allowed to bring domain knowledge to the problem. But you can also use feature importance measures, tree models, CV, or L1 regularization (etc, etc) to help prove your hypothesis that the features are not useful. That's what data science is all about.